# What does the error message about pip --use-feature=2020-resolver mean?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install jupyter on Ubuntu 16.04.6 x64 on DigitalOcean droplet. It is giving me the following error message, and I can't understand what this means.

> ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or
> updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it
> resolves dependency conflicts.
>
> We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages
> with the new resolver before it becomes the default.
>
> jsonschema 3.2.0 requires six>=1.11.0, but you'll have six 1.10.0 which is incompatible

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Execute these commands: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, `pip check` and finally install your package using `pip install <PACKAGE> --use-feature=2020-resolver`. This will install the correct versions for the dependencies.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to [this announcement](https://discuss.python.org/t/announcement-pip-20-2-release/4863), pip will introduce a new dependency resolver in October 2020, which will be more robust but might break some existing setups. Therefore they are suggesting users to try running their pip install scripts at least once (in dev mode) with this option: `--use-feature=2020-resolver`
to anticipate any potential issue before the new resolver becomes the default in October 2020 with pip version 20.3.

> On behalf of the PyPA, I am pleased to announce that we have just released pip 20.2, a new version of pip. You can install it by running python -m pip install --upgrade pip.
>
> The highlights for this release are:
>
> - The beta of the next-generation dependency resolver is available
> - Faster installations from wheel files
> - Improved handling of wheels containing non-ASCII file contents
> - Faster pip list using parallelized network operations
> - Installed packages now contain metadata about whether they were directly
>   requested by the user (PEP 376’s REQUESTED file)
>
> The new dependency resolver is off by default because it is not yet ready for everyday use.
>
> The new dependency resolver is significantly stricter and more consistent when it receives incompatible instructions, and reduces support for certain kinds of constraints files, so some workarounds and workflows may break. Please test it with the --use-feature=2020-resolver flag. Please see [our guide on how to test and migrate](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-2-2020), and how to report issues . We are preparing to change the default dependency resolution behavior and make the new resolver the default in pip 20.3 (in October 2020).

Comment: Can one use the `--use-feature=2020-resolver` command when running a pip install of a requirement.txt file?

Comment: Yes. Well it depends on your version of pip. Pip's latest version is now 21.0 and since 20.3 the new resolver is automatically used so the option has no effect. So, if you forced pip to stay < 20.3, which still uses the old resolver, you can use this option to use the new resolver instead and check if you will have issues going >= 20.3.
As can be seen in this email thread below, several open source tools got broken by this change and now requires to keep an old pip version until things get sorted out: https://www.mail-archive.com/users@airflow.apache.org/msg00442.html)

Answer (score 66):

First check if your `pip` is updated:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then use:

```
pip install example --use-feature=2020-resolver
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Yap, had to upgrade pip first otherwise got `no such option: --use-feature` when pip install. This answer was helpful!

Comment: @naveganteJP , I have all requirmenst in `requirments.txt` file, and if i try this command `pip install -r requirments.txt  --use-feature=2020-resolver`, it is returning an error. Can you please suggest a solution for installing requirments.txt file

Comment: @siva : just fix your dependencies

Comment: i received `pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 21.0.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))` ... so for me it probably broke ...

Comment: How do we run the two lines from requirements.txt? @J-ECasta I did not understand your comment on fixing dependency.