# Error when installing django on windows using `pip install django`

Tags: python, django, pip, dependencies

I get an error when installing `django` using `pip` command

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating
packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the
new resolver before it becomes the default.

drf-yasg 1.17.0 requires six>=1.10.0, but you'll have six 1.9.0 which is incompatible.
```

can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63277123/what-is-use-feature-2020-resolver-error-message-with-jupyter-installation-on

Comment: But how should I now install `django` can you help me on which command shold be used to install `django`

Comment: pip install django

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the error message about pip --use-feature=2020-resolver mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63277123/what-does-the-error-message-about-pip-use-feature-2020-resolver-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this announcement](https://discuss.python.org/t/announcement-pip-20-2-release/4863), pip will introduce a new dependency resolver in October 2020, which will be more robust but might break some existing setups. Therefore they are suggesting users to try running their pip install scripts at least once (in dev mode) with this option: --use-feature=2020-resolver to anticipate any potential issue before the new resolver becomes the default in October 2020 with pip version 20.3.

> On behalf of the PyPA, I am pleased to announce that we have just
> released pip 20.2, a new version of pip. You can install it by running
> python -m pip install --upgrade pip.
>
> The highlights for this release are:
>
> The beta of the next-generation dependency resolver is available
> Faster installations from wheel files Improved handling of wheels
> containing non-ASCII file contents Faster pip list using parallelized
> network operations Installed packages now contain metadata about
> whether they were directly requested by the user (PEP 376’s REQUESTED
> file) The new dependency resolver is off by default because it is not
> yet ready for everyday use. The new dependency resolver is
> significantly stricter and more consistent when it receives
> incompatible instructions, and reduces support for certain kinds of
> constraints files, so some workarounds and workflows may break. Please
> test it with the --use-feature=2020-resolver flag. Please see [our
> guide on how to test and migrate](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-2-2020), and how to report issues. We are
> preparing to change the default dependency resolution behaviour and
> make the new resolver the default in pip 20.3 (in October 2020).