# About Automatic playing YouTube video into clubhouse

Tags: youtube, live-streaming, auto

I am trying to write some codes for automatically playing one online radio into clubhouse Android application, so if possible I like to have some comment for:

> Finding some  python or php codes to play automatically live-streaming from YouTube by
> using [the Google Colaboratory environment](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb?utm_source=scs-index), like the result of the below Google search results:
>
> [Automate clubhouse Messages With Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=Automate%20cluhouse%20Messages%20With%20Python&rlz=1C1BNSD_enIR973IR973&sxsrf=AOaemvKQdPnGsEnoVtF95X28pYE7WYTcNg%3A1633274354061&ei=8slZYbSEA633qwHv75vIBg&ved=0ahUKEwi0xcaNxa7zAhWt-yoKHe_3BmkQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=Automate%20cluhouse%20Messages%20With%20Python&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABQ1gJY0BJg3xRoAHAEeACAAfIGiAGxGJIBBzQtMS4zLjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

**Update 1:**

I have found two result from the Google, which could be seen below:

1. [A third-part web application based on flask to play Clubhouse
   audio](https://pythonawesome.com/a-third-part-web-application-based-on-flask-to-play-clubhouse-audio/)
2. [A simple script that will watch a stream for you and earn the
   channel points.](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/Tkd-Alex-Twitch-Channel-Points-Miner-v2)

And tried to run the above first instruction on the Google colab ([link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/soheilpaper/-tft-2.4-ili9341-STM32/blob/master/NLP_NER_Pharmacovigilance.ipynb)) but get the below error:
[image]

```
!git clone https://github.com/ai-eks/OpenClubhouse-Worker
%cd OpenClubhouse-Worker
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
Cloning into 'OpenClubhouse-Worker'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 61, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (61/61), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done.
remote: Total 61 (delta 31), reused 38 (delta 14), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (61/61), done.
/content/OpenClubhouse-Worker
Collecting pymongo==3.11.3
  Downloading pymongo-3.11.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (512 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 512 kB 5.2 MB/s 
Collecting requests==2.25.1
  Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61 kB 6.8 MB/s 
Collecting requests-openapi==0.9.7
  Downloading requests_openapi-0.9.7-py3-none-any.whl (5.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests==2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests==2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests==2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests==2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests-openapi==0.9.7->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (3.13)
Installing collected packages: requests, requests-openapi, pymongo
  Attempting uninstall: requests
    Found existing installation: requests 2.23.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.23.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.23.0
  Attempting uninstall: pymongo
    Found existing installation: pymongo 3.12.0
    Uninstalling pymongo-3.12.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pymongo-3.12.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires requests~=2.23.0, but you have requests 2.25.1 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed pymongo-3.11.3 requests-2.25.1 requests-openapi-0.9.7
```

So I am trying to make it by updating the question and working based of the comments.

**Update 2:**

Based on the help of [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12511801/marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes) the first error fixed, and I have got a new error, as you can see [below](https://colab.research.google.com/github/soheilpaper/-tft-2.4-ili9341-STM32/blob/master/NLP_NER_Pharmacovigilance.ipynb):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 26, in main
    chh = ClubHouseHelper(phone=phone, url=api_uri, device_id=device_id)
  File "/content/OpenClubhouse-Worker/OpenClubhouse-Worker/OpenClubhouse-Worker/OpenClubhouse-Worker/ch_helper.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.client.load_spec_from_file(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_openapi/core.py", line 252, in load_spec_from_file
    spec = load_spec_from_file(file_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_openapi/core.py", line 159, in load_spec_from_file
    return yaml.load(spec_str, Loader=yaml.Loader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 70, in load
    loader = Loader(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/loader.py", line 34, in __init__
    Reader.__init__(self, stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.check_printable(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 144, in check_printable
    'unicode', "special characters are not allowed")
yaml.reader.ReaderError: unacceptable character #x1f579: special characters are not allowed
  in "<unicode string>", position 6373
```

Thanks.

Comment: interesting, do you have the specifics about which live-stream and/or a better definition of the desired results?

Comment: @Marco_Aurelio_Fernandez_Reyes, I have updated the Question and tried to run some codes on colab pages and add the errors I have get.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034730/12511801).

Comment: Well done by solving the first issue :) about the second issue, I searched and `#x1f579` is a joystick emoticon:   - [source](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2016-10/msg00696.html). Can you get by separate the result you're getting?  This message: `unacceptable character #x1f579: special characters are not allowed
  in "<unicode string>", position 6373` is about the response - here, you have to check how those characters can be allowed of replaced, if you have researched about this error, share your results here.